# añadir carpeta adicional a Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

Amigos quiero crear más carpetas adicionales a las que trae el Framework Laravel 5 para colocar mis propias clases personalizadas.

Deseo crear las capas como por ejemplo: Datos, Negocio, etc con sus respectivas clases php dentro de cada una de ellas.

El problema viene cuando Laravel 5 no detecta dichas clases porque estan en directorios nuevos.

En Laravel 4 se solucionaba en app/start/global.php y se agregaban

ClassLoader::addDirectories(array())

pero en Laravel 5 no encuentro dicha configuración, gracias.

Comment: no las detecta por que están en directorios nuevos ?, yo he agregado las carpetas que quiero y archivos también, solo hay que cuidarse de los namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> No entendiste, quiero agregar más carpetas dentro de app, porque
>   quiero realizar una aplicación por capas: Entidades, Datos, Negocio
>   con sus respectivas clases php, pero si creo esas carpetas al momento
>   de intentar utilizarlas Laravel 5 no las detecta.

En composer ya todo está escrito. Solo cree las carpetas que usted prefiera, por ejemplo:

> app/Negocio/

Usted crea una clase allí adentro usando el namespace correspondiente:

```
<?php
namespace App\Negocio;

class Hola{}
```

Finalmente en su proyecto, puede utlizar la clase sin mayor inconveniente, por ejemplo, en un controlador:

```
public function index(){
    $hola = new \App\Negocio\Hola();
}
```

Si la clase no es encontrada, entonces use el comando `composer dump-autoload` para actualizar un mapa de clases que pueden ser cargadas en su proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

No se si estoy entendiendo bien su pregunta, si lo que usted quiere es crear un directorio para almacenar digamos sus `.css`, por ejemplo usted lo puede hacer de la misma manera que cuando quiere crear un directorio, en cualquier lugar de su OS, si lo que desea es crealo dentro de public, dirijase `../laravel/public` y cree el directorio como habitualmente desde consola o desde el explorador "algo si como boton derecho del mouse, crear folder o algo asi", por ejemplo con el nombre `estilos` ahora tendria una cosa similar a esto `../laravel/public/estilos` y dentro guarde o cree lo que necesite.

---

pero si lo que quiere es crearla en tiempo puede usar eso:

`File::makeDirectory()` metodo.

ejemplo:

```
$resultado = File::makeDirectory('/ruta/en/nombreDirectorio');
```

ejemplo:

```
$resultado = File::makeDirectory('/ruta/en/nombreDirectorio', 0775);
```

ejemplo recursivo con el uso de true:

```
$result = File::makeDirectory('/rutaNoExi/enNoExi/nombreDirectorio', 0775, true);
```

---

pude que quiera mirar esto para ver como Laravel tiene organizada su estructura https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/structure#the-root-directory , igual es bueno que tenga en cuenta los permisos que laravel usa para sus directorios, o el servidor que usa para su proyecto a la hora de crear los directorios

---

**Update:**

Igual tiene que haces uso de http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/ puede leer algo aqui https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-app-directory,

Si su fichero solo contine la funciones puede tratar algo asi en su `composer.json`

```
},
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/suDirectorio/suFuncion.php"
        ]
    },
```

Si es una clase `.php` (psr-4)

```
"psr-4": {
            "SuApp\\": "app/"
        },
```

---

tambien puede usar el namespace, dentro de su fichero, (sin hacer cambios en el composer)

```
<?php
namespace suApp\suDirectorioDentroApp;
   class miFuncion {
     public function laQueTenga() {
..//
?>
```

---

```
<?php
 $Funcion1 = new suApp\suDirectorioDentroApp\miFuncion;
 $test = ($Function1->laQueTenga());
 ?>
```

---

composer dump-autoload

---

*dependiendo de su version igual tiene que usar una u otra*

Comment: No entendiste, quiero agregar más carpetas dentro de app, porque quiero realizar una aplicación por capas: Entidades, Datos, Negocio con sus respectivas clases php, pero si creo esas carpetas al momento de intentar utilizarlas Laravel 5 no las detecta.

Comment: @EvolutionxD usted dice -> No entendiste, quiero agregar más carpetas dentro de app... en ningun momento dice nada parecido en su pregunta y que laravel no las detecta, igual deberia de agregar esta informacion a su pregunta original, o tener encuenta el agregar cuanto mas detalles posibles a su/s preguntas pues sera mas facil para que los usuarios puedan ayudarle, no se lo tome a mal pero la gente no es adivina Saludos